# How to use JIRA for traking project issues

Tags: jira

I installed JIRA 6.4. I also Crerated Project and Issue in it. I assigned Issue to some user. Now If Administrator wants to monitor isssue status, he can see progress. But how does the asignee i.e the person working on issue update issue status. Actually I am very new to JIRA. Or is there any other plugin for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the workflow you have configured for the project, the assignee should see action buttons on the issue that they can click to progress status; e.g. "Resolve Issue" or "Close Issue". These are known as "Transitions" in the workflow and configure how issues can move between certain states.

If you're also using the JIRA Agile add-on, you can create a "Rapid Board" that allows assignees to drag and drop issues between states to create a "Work in Progress" board.

This is just a starter, it's best to run through the tutorials from Atlassian, they will take into account the various project setups that may apply to you.

Also, if you're just getting up and running with JIRA, it may be advisable to upgrade to JIRA Core 7 (or JIRA Software if you require the extra features) as it has project templates/workflows that will make getting up and running a lot quicker.

Comment: Hey thanx for the reply. Is it possible to use JIRA for Splitting bills among friends that are users?